# java Kafka Producer- send large amount of messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to send 300,000 messages to Kafka topic, each message with size ~1500 bytes.

The first 299,996 messages are sent is last than a minute, but then Kafka hangs out for a while and doesn’t send the rest of the messages. Very strange.

My Kafka producer configuration:

```
    private void initKafka() {
    Properties configProperties = new Properties();
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaLocation);
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(configProperties);
}
```

My code:

```
    for (ResponseDocument responseDocument : documents.getDocuments()) {
                try {
                    LinkedHashMap<String, Collection<? extends Object>> fields = convertToMap(responseDocument);
                    String jsonDoc = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(fields);
                    String docId =  responseDocument.getFirstValueAsString(".id");
                    ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(kafkaTopic, docId, jsonDoc);
                    kafkaProducer.send(record);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error(ErrorCode.DATA_ACCESS_ERROR, "Failed to send document with .id {0}: {1}",responseDocument.getId(), e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

I tried to play a little bit with the configuration, number of sent messages (changed to 250,000) and some more thinks..

Any idea?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Any warnings or errors in Kafka broker logs? What configuration params did you change?

Comment: What version of Kafka is this?

Comment: no warnings/errors in logs. didn't change any configuration. my Kafka version is 0.10.0.1. i have checked my logs and it seems that "docId" is sometimes null. does sending a record with key=null could be the reason?